# My brake pads on one wheel only last a month or 2 each time I change them?

Tags: pontiac, brake-rotor, brake-calipers, brake-pad, g6

I have a 2007 Pontiac G6, 4 cylinder.

About a 4 months ago in January I almost got hit by a Dodge Durango that ran a light and almost crushed me literally headed straight for the driver door. So i threw my car sideways to avoid me getting hit and just the back of the car, but i went all the way sideways and avoid it altogether but could not come back out of it and hit the side of a curb with that wheel.

So took it to Firestone and they said they could not see and bends or damages to anything except the wheel was out of alignment and tire was bent so i got that done that day new tire and rim.

A week or so later my brakes began to grind so I knew my pads were out got them changed out (same wheel btw). Now here is where things get confusing. Two months after that the pads went out again.

Obviously they are supposed to last longer than that so we thought maybe the caliper was damaged. We didn't take any chances so we changed the caliper, the rotor and the pads.

A month later the pads went out again at this point I have no idea what is causing this to happen. I need help because I don't want to replace everything again after a month.  Any ideas, appreciate the help if possible

Comment: Seems pretty obviously a bent caliper mount, did you inspect the pads? they will probably show wear on one end more than the other.  Additionally, does your wheel get extremely hot? do you get worse mileage? does the car pull to one side?

Comment: Yep bad caliper.

Comment: Is there any shaking or noises at any speed? If you tug really hard on the wheel in question, is there any movement? You may have damaged the wheel hub or wheel bearing, which could allow the rotor to rub on the pads. I highly doubt the brake caliper mounting bracket would bend without breaking, as they are normally fairly thick chunks of metal that are cast as part of the knuckle / hub carrier.

Comment: Another thing to check is the brake hardlines. If they get bent, kinked or dinged they may be holding pressure at the wheel and allowing the pads to drag constantly. But that usually requires some frame bending to accomplish.

Comment: Feel your wheels (or if you're brave, briefly touch the rotor) after a short drive; is the wheel you complain about noticeably hotter than the other front wheel?

Comment: maybe during your ride to the curb the bent wheel also touched the caliper(s) and you might need to change them, also check the disc for damages

Comment: @MooseLucifer +1!!! Very unlikely that you could damage the caliper mount at all without the impact being *very significant*. The hub and bearings are ***much*** more sensitive. My wife trashed her wheel bearings by slightly clipping a curb several years ago and it blew my mind how easily they got damaged.

Comment: Did they only change one tire, and then change only one pad? That would be part of the problem - tires and brakes are supposed to be changed in pairs (front pair, or rear pair), unless they are fairly new. This helps to even out the wear, and it's why brakes are usually sold as front or rear sets. Beyond that, you probably have a wheel bearing problem, or some error with the tie rod and/or control rod (the metal rod that actually steers the tire when you turn the steering wheel). It sounds like all braking force is applied to that one wheel, as that's a rapid wear rate.

Answer (score 1):

As other people in the comments said it's likely caliper related, Either a bent caliper mount or a sticking caliper piston, either way the pad is being constantly pressed against the disc and being worn down as a result of that.

One way i was taught to check for such an issue is try touching the wheel nuts/bolts after a long(ish) drive, if there too hot to touch then chances are the pads are rubbing on the disc causing friction/heat buildup and the heat is then transferred throughout the wheel and hub

Answer (score -1):

I would have them check to see if any abs codes might have been stored and also have them check wheel speed sensor/tone wheel. Maybe it got damaged in the accident and is reading incorrectly to where to abs module is applying the brakes to that wheel inorder to slow it down.